# Android: torrent intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bittorrent

I have a couple of apps installed to download torrents (Ttorrent, UTorrent etc..) but when I run this code in my app

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setType("application/x-bittorrent");
    i.setData(Uri.parse(movie.getTorrentUrl()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "view"));
```

I get "no apps can perform this action" dialog.

Comment: Did Bittorrent exist in  your phone?

Comment: yes, it exists ! If I remove the addCategory line the chooser starts and it shows the torrent apps, but it show also browser apps. I'd like to show only torrent app in the chooser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved getting an intent for every app that can handle my action, and then I perform some filters based on intent package name (in my case I check if the package contains "torrent" word). Here the code:

```
  public Intent generateTorrentIntent(Context context, String action, Intent intent) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (resolveInfo.size() > 0) {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        for (ResolveInfo r : resolveInfo) {
            Intent progIntent = (Intent)intent.clone();
            String packageName = r.activityInfo.packageName;

            progIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            if (r.activityInfo.packageName.contains("torrent"))
                targetedShareIntents.add(progIntent);

        }
        if (targetedShareIntents.size() > 0) {
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0),
                    "Select app to share");

            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));

            return chooserIntent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Since you solved your issue with this answer, please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, those applications do not support that particular `Intent` structure. For example, perhaps whatever scheme is in that URL is one that they do not understand.

You might consider talking to their respective authors, asking them if there is some sort of `Intent` that you could use for this sort of operation, and whether the could add one if they do not already support something.